# How to replace only once and no in tag?

Tags: php

I need to replace names in my text on site. But the name in text only needs to be replaced, and not in tag .

For example:

```
<img src="" title="Justin Bieber" /> bla bla bla bla Justin Bieber bla bla bla Justin Bieber bla bla bla bla
```

To this:

```
<img src="" title="Justin Bieber" /> bla bla bla bla <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Bieber">Justin Bieber</a> bla bla bla Justin Bieber bla bla bla bla
```

**I've found answer:**

```
$text = '<img src="" title="Justin Bieber" /> bla bla bla bla Justin Bieber bla bla bla Justin Bieber bla bla bla bla';

$text = preg_replace('/Justin Bieber(?![^<>]*+>)/i', '<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Bieber">Justin Bieber</a>', $text, 1);
```

Only one and no in image tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are parsing HTML of any complexity, use an HTML parser. Search for "HTML Parser" on this site and you will get many, many results.

If you are dealing with small, controlled strings, use a regular expression.

Here is a **very** simple example: http://regexr.com?2vjqc

It simply checks to see if "Justin Bieber" is within quotes (as it should be within an HTML tag). There are a dozen ways that this can fail (spaces, missing quotes, quotes elsewhere in the document, malformed tags, etc.)

Of course, this regex could be improved but if you don't have control over the source, I strongly recommend using an HTML parser rather than a regex.

Answer (score -2):

```
$text = '<img src="" title="Justin Bieber" /> bla bla bla bla Justin Bieber bla bla bla Justin Bieber bla bla bla bla';
$replacement = '<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Bieber">Justin Bieber</a>';
echo preg_replace('/\s+Justin Bieber/i', $replacement, $text, 1);
```

Comment: -1. Don't parse HTML with REGEX. It will break. What if he had `<img src="" title="Image of Justin Bieber">`?

Comment: @Truth Yep your right. If the HTML is well formated you could use SimpleXML to iterate DOM get text only, replace and recreate html.